# UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle

Tags: xcode

I need serious advice here after tinkering myself the last few days.

I am looking for an example/advice on how for the above mentioned UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle.

See here for example:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewStyles/TableViewCharacteristics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH3-SW14

The rows need to be editable on one of the labels and uploading a photo from photos on device(is that even possible?)

Also id like to commit the user input of the cells into an array for future calculations.

Thanks and kind regards,

Trev

Answer (score 0):

```
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```